# How to create a Debian package for my Java Web Application?

Tags: java, web-applications, debian, packaging

[Kunagi](http://kunagi.org) is a simple Java Web application for which we are already creating a binary `.deb` package for our users. This package depends on `tomcat6` and just puts the `.war` file into `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`. This works great on Debian and Ubuntu.

Now I want to create a real source package which can be integrated to Debian. Sadly I can not find any tutorial. There is a lot of fractioned information about tools like CDBS, DH7 or javahelper and their commands. But which one should I use?

I also have some conceptual questions:

1. Usualy, web applications are installed by copying the webapp into the `webapps` directory of the web container. Would it then be right to make my package dependent on `tomcat6` and install my webapp directly into `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`? Or should my webapp be installed somewhere else, providing a separate Tomcat configuration and run with its own user, like other services do?
2. My webapp uses libraries (JARs) from other projects. Usualy these are placed in the `WEB-INF/lib` subdirectory of the webapp directory. Since including libraries in a package is not allowed in Debian, would it be right to add these projects as dependencies into my package and create symlinks in my `WEB-INF/lib` directory? Or how would I solve this problem?
3. My webapp needs to write files (application data). Since Tomcat is running as user `www-data` on Debian, the only directory where my webapp can write is `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`. Is it the right place to put my data? Or should my package create something like `/var/lib/my-webapp-name/` and grant write permissions for user `www-data`?

Comment: What is the best way to inform debian developers about this question here?

Comment: you have a deb package to put the war on tomcat. Could you possibly share that? We are trying to do the same thing.

Comment: It is really needs to be a .deb package? You can create docker conatiner (https://www.docker.com/) with tomcat and your webapp. Containers works like virtual machines, bud docker let you to make changes easily, and share it. Your client need just to install docker from Debian repository and run one command to download and run your container. I can give you an example if this can be considered as a solution. Your container can already have embedded tomcat, you can just to modify this public container image (https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/).

Comment: I don't want my users have to install docker to use my application. I would like them just to klick on my package, like it works in modern app stores. Sadly this is nearly impossible for Debian :-(

Answer (score 2):

Well... If you have to create Debian package than there is a great [jdeb](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb) library which works for both [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [maven](https://maven.apache.org/). The best feature is that it does not require any `dpkg` wrappers so your build will not be os-dependent.